# Group By sem 'mesclar' rótulos de dados python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Olá, pessoal, tenho o dataframe abaixo e preciso agrupar e somar as colunas. Para isso estou usando o groupby, porém no resultado os rótulos são cancatenados, existe uma forma de isso não acontecer?

Na coluna 'codes' gostaria que para cada linha repetisse o código.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

codes=['2', '2', '2', '3','3','3', '2', '3']
ano_mes=['201809', '201809', '201809', '201809','201809','201809', '201810', '201810']
produto=['Meal', 'Meal', 'Meal', 'Food', 'Food', 'Food', 'Food', 'Food']
sales=[200,300,400,200,300,300,200, 150]
receita=[2,3,4,2,3,3,2,1.5]


df = pd.DataFrame({'codes': codes,
                   'ano_mes':ano_mes,
                   'produto': produto,
                  'sales': sales,
                  'receita': receita})

df_2 = df.groupby(['codes', 'ano_mes', 'produto']).sum()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode "resetar" o index fazendo uso da função `reset_index()` para que todos os valores sejam mostrados:

```py
...
df_2 = df.groupby(['codes', 'ano_mes','produto']).sum().reset_index().to_string(index=False)
```

Ou (para melhor visualização):

```py
...
df_2 = df.groupby(['codes', 'ano_mes', 'produto']).sum()
df_2 = df_2.reset_index().to_string(index=False)
```

Feito isso, o output de `df_2` ficará da forma que você deseja:

```
codes ano_mes produto  sales  receita
    2  201809    Meal    900      9.0
    2  201810    Food    200      2.0
    3  201809    Food    800      8.0
    3  201810    Food    150      1.5
```

A função `reset_index()` tem como função "resetar" o index do DataFrame e usar o index padrão no lugar.

Comment: Perfeito, deu certo! Super obrigado!

Comment: Show! Se a resposta o ajudou por gentileza a marque como aceita clicando ali no afirmativo que fica próximo às setinhas de votar :)

Comment: Feito. Obrigado!